# Unregistering a zeroconf service using jmDNS

Tags: android, zeroconf, mdns, dns-sd

I'm tryng to make my Android app register a service via zeroconf while the app is active, and then unregister it after the app exits.  In my onResume method I have the following code:

```
    // register ourselves with zero conf
    try {
        JmDNS jmdns = JmDNS.create();

        serviceInfo = ServiceInfo.create("_http._tcp.local.", "My App Service", SERVER_PORT, 0, 0, false, "path=/crazycatapp");
        jmdns.registerService(serviceInfo);
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        Debug.e("Error registering service with zeroconf", t);
    }
```

and then subsequently in my onPause method:

```
    if(serviceInfo != null) {

            // unregister ourselves with zero conf
            JmDNS jmdns = JmDNS.create();
            jmdns.unregisterService(serviceInfo);
        }
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        Debug.e("Error unregistering service with zeroconf", t);
    }
```

I've elimintated the code that does multicast enabling, etc.  The point is, I can register the service just fine, and can subsequently see it using a zeroconf browser on another device.  However, once registered, the service never disappears unless I actually disable the wifi on the device that registered the service.  The call to unregisterService doesn't seem to actually affect a service registration.  unregisterAllServices doesn't seem to have any effect either.  Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at the relevant code in `JmDNS` I think you should unregister your `ServiceInfo` from the same `JmDNS` instance you registered it with. So you'll have to keep the `jmdns` reference from your registration snippet around and call unregister on that one, instead of the new instance you create in your unregister snippet.